# Surpress Jupyter Notebook magic commands notifications

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

this is a quick one. I am using the `%run` magic command to run an OLS regression which is within another Jupyter Notebook. I use the `%store` magic to pass data between the notebooks. My code is below:

```
for targs in gen_targets(d_targets.columns):
    for feats in gen_feats(feat_lst):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X[feats],
                                                            y[targs],
                                                            test_size=0.2)

        model_id = analysis_id + "_" + targs +'~'+' + '.join(feats)
        %store X_train #Store X training data
        %store y_train #Store y training data
        %store model_id  #Store Model ID 
        %run OLS_Regression.ipynb #Run the Regression
        %store -r model #The regression instance (in case I want to use it)
        %store -r model_results #Summary of model results (dic)

        results = results.append(model_results, ignore_index = True)
```

However, when I run this, I get a message about the storage. An example is shown below

```
Stored 'X_train' (DataFrame)
Stored 'y_train' (Series)
Stored 'model_id' (str)
Stored 'model_results' (dict)
Stored 'model' (RegressionResultsWrapper)
Stored 'X_train' (DataFrame)
Stored 'y_train' (Series)
Stored 'model_id' (str)
Stored 'model_results' (dict)
Stored 'model' (RegressionResultsWrapper)
Stored 'X_train' (DataFrame)
Stored 'y_train' (Series)
Stored 'model_id' (str)
Stored 'model_results' (dict)
```

As my combinations of features and targets can be quite long, this is overwhelming the output.

Is it possible to suppress this output?

PS: If you think I can improve upon the code, then please let me know. I am still *'learning'*. I know I have not added a model prediction check, hence the Test train split may seem redundant, but it will be used.

Many thanks.